# Error when using :Ex after :Lexplore

Tags: neovim

I am starting to use Neovim and in the process of configuring the text editor. While doing some test I found that every time I try to open a file using the `:Ex` command I get the error:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>28_NetrwBrowseChgDir
line  172:
E471: Argument required: keepj keepalt 2wincmd 1
```

Only if I previously had used the `:Lexplore` command.

I have no idea why this happens neither how to solve it, so I appreciate all the feedback you can give me.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in netrw. Please file a report with Dr Chip or on theVim repository

Comment: @D.BenKnoble shouldn't I report to the neovim repository, I don't know what those two are?

Comment: No: Netrw is the plugin that ships with Vim and provides the :Explore family of commands. (I didn't realize Neovim even still shipped Netrw, actually. They mostly copy over stuff like that from Vim, though.) Dr. Chip is the maintainer. Try `:edit $VIMRUNTIME/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim` or `:help pi_netrw` for contact info.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble  Damn, you really do know a lot! I really appreciate your help. Thank you for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon that issue too. It seems to me that with 99% its Lex bug. I switched to Vex + some tunning and that works fine. With Lex I couldn't make Ex open files after Lex =\

Update 2. Sorry. New observations) I made full analogue of Lex with Vex and ....
is start behave like Lex.
More inspections lead me to -- vim.g.netrw_browse_split = 4. Exactly this thing make all this work wrong. If you can normally handle it (like I'm trying right now) I suppose you can I achieve this sfuff working.

Update 3. Yes it works. If when I open Lex/Vex I set vim.g.netrw_browse_split = 4, but when I open Ex revert it to default vim.g.netrw_browse_split = 0 all works like a charm.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).